# Swift - 2 empty string arrays

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to find out why sometimes this happens in swift/Xcode. When I check "employees.isEmpty" is returns correctly because it is empty. When is check "uids.isEmpty" it return empty as well but for some reason it thinks there are values and then executes my firebase call which of course crashes the app because the array is nil. Why does this happen? Same code. Same set up. Yet "employees.isEmpty" returns nil like it should (in my testing) and the other "uids.isEmpty" is empty but executes like there are values when there are not.

```
if employees.isEmpty == false {
    print("This shouldnt be called 1")
    OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "\(message)"],
                                "include_player_ids": employees,
                                "headings": ["en": "Hey \(businessName)"],
                                "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
                                "ios_badgeCount": 1])
} else {
    print("Empty no execution")
}
print(employees)
print("Checking inside employees here")
print(uids)
print("Checking inside uids here")

if uids.isEmpty == false {
    print("This shouldnt be called 2")
    let pathing = ref.child("notification").child(uids).childByAutoId()
    pathing.setValue(values)
} else {
    print("Empty no execution")
}
```

They both print out the same when no values are assigned, just like this: "[]".

**Declarations/Appending**

```
var data:[String] = []
var dataUID:[String] = []


// GETTING THE ONESIGNAL ID'S FROM THE EMPLOYEES FOR NOTIFICATIONS
func getEmployees() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).child("registered_employees").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
           let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let uid = data?["onesignal"] as? String
            self.data.append(uid!)
            print(self.data)
        } else {
            print("didnt call right values")
        }
    })
}

func getEmployeesUIDs() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Businesses").child(self.otherUser?["uid"] as! String).child("registered_employees").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let uid = data?["uid"] as? String
            self.dataUID.append(uid!)
            print(self.dataUID)
            print("Printing the employee uids right here")
        } else {
            print("didnt call right values")
        }
    })
}


let employees = self.data
let uids = self.dataUID.description

if employees.isEmpty {
                print("Empty no execution")
            } else {
                print("This shouldnt be called 1")
                OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "\(message)"],
                                            "include_player_ids": employees,
                                            "headings": ["en": "Hey \(businessName)"],
                                            "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
                                            "ios_badgeCount": 1])
            }
            print(employees)
            print("Checking inside employees here")
            print(uids)
            print("Checking inside uids here")

            if uids.isEmpty {
                print("Empty no execution")
            } else {
                print("This shouldnt be called 2")
                let pathing = ref.child("notification").child(uids).childByAutoId()
                pathing.setValue(values)

            }
```

Comment: This is probably not relevant, but never say `uids.isEmpty == false`. `isEmpty` is already a Bool; do not compare it to something else. Just say `if !uids.isEmpty`.

Comment: how do you init employees and uids?

Comment: As for actual question, it would probably help us to know how `employees` and `uids` are declared and how / when they are populated. You say the array is `nil`; that suggests it is an Optional. That could be important to know. And it might be that you are populating these arrays asynchronously, in which case there may be a code-out-of-order issue that you are not showing us yet.

Comment: Added the extra code

Comment: its just weird one works and the other does not when they are both set up exactly the same

Comment: One has `.description`, not exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I think that's dumb if when you add ".description" the functionality of checking inside the array is different.

Comment: Ok, so for my "getEmployees()" firebase call, it is not being called correctly. Since I am testing for when there are no "registered_employees" the "snapshot" should return that it doesn't exist, yet it doesn't

Comment: You are checking inside a String in case of `uids`, not an Array.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am testing everything. I think I'll get it working after everyones help

Comment: Thank you OOPer, I think I got it to work because of removing ".description" and then adding it when making a firebase call. Going to test if it saves correctly after employees register to the business thus adding values not making these checks nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if employees.isEmpty == false {
    print("This shouldnt be called 1")
    OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "\(message)"],
                                "include_player_ids": employees,
                                "headings": ["en": "Hey \(businessName)"],
                                "ios_badgeType": "Increase",
                                "ios_badgeCount": 1])
} else {
    print("Empty no execution")

    print(employees)
    print("Checking inside employees here")
    print(uids)
    print("Checking inside uids here")}

    if uids.isEmpty == false {
        print("This shouldnt be called 2")
        let pathing = ref.child("notification").child(uids).childByAutoId()
        pathing.setValue(values)
    } else {
        print("Empty no execution")
    }
```

Try the above code. I have moved the part where you show the array in else so that if array is nil it will show.